# Visual Studio doesn't show anything when app crashes

Tags: c#, asynchronous, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, uwp

I'm debugging an app on a Windows 10 Mobile phone (Lumia 550) from Visual Studio on my PC. At some point the app simply closes on the phone and it shows the start screen.

The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't show anything. Not an exception, not even stops debugging. Though sometimes it does hang, usually not.

I created a breakpoint and it seems (but I'm not sure of that) to run fine until it tries to return from an async method, perhaps to a caller that doesn't exist anymore. That's when the app crashes. I then removed the "await" and verified that the method is executed, and (on a separate run) - that the code after it is executed. Both run, and the crash is after them.

I realize that this is not enough for you to tell me why is the app crashing. That's not my question. **My question is how** is it that VS doesn't catch an exception and just keeps waiting for the device. And what can be done about that. The information I've given is because perhaps it might be pertinent.

Comment: I've experienced that, you need to go with `try..catch` blocks and printing error messages to the console in order to figure out what is wrong. Or place break points inside the catch. It is really frustrating.

Comment: @user3185569 This is all happening (as far as I can tell) _within_ a try-catch block and the catch never captures anything. I agree, it is really quite frustrating.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the app.xaml's unhandled exception event does it tell you anything?

Comment: @KenTucker Thanks. But it's never hit.

Comment: @ispiro this behaviour can occur when you use async void method instead of async Task - while there is no return value and method is "promise-like", reference to this method is just lost and it lives on its own, and it crashes on its own, so visual studio will not catch any exception in such method

Comment: @Qerts Thanks. But a) It's a `Task<bool>`, and b) The async _should_ crash on its own and leave the app running. It doesn't.

Comment: There are global event handlers you should register so as to capture such exceptions and analyze. Search for them via Google.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. But see the 3rd and 4th comments.

Comment: "app.xaml's unhandled exception event"? For tasks, you should use UnobservedTaskException as [this indicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5).

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. I need to try that now. Though I doubt it'll help because [its docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) say `.NET Framework 4.5 changes the default exception behavior ... the process does not terminate by default.`.

Comment: @LexLi Update: `UnobservedTaskException` is not executed.

Comment: We would like to get in touch with you to know more about this. Can you send an email to debugger[at]microsoft[dot]com Once we know the root cause and the solution, we'll post it here for the benefit of the community